# Chrome: print graph takes too long

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, google-chrome, printing, jqplot

I have a View with a Jqplot graph. 
For printing I use browser's print option (I use print.css)

When I print a very simple jqplot graph (Two Bars), the file sent to the printer has a size nerly to 30 MB and printer takes too long to respond. The same thing sending the graph to a pdf creator.

Browser print preview works fast.

Im using:

- Google Chrome 19
- Asp. Net MVC3
- Jqplot Version: 1.0.0b2_r1012

This is graph's CSS:

```
#regimenCajaReductora
{
    height: 200px;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
    float: none;
}
```

Could you help me with this problem? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I tried it using IE9. The file sent to the printer was nearly to 3 MB. 10 times smaller than Chrome 19.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching I found this:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=92304

There is an issue in Google Chrome's Print preview (ctrl+p). Print from there produces a **massive file 10/15 times bigger** than the one obtained from "Advanced" option.

When I printed using Chrome's advanced print option (ctrl+shift+p) the file size sent to the printer was normal size.